# asp.net gridview viewstate , too much data (overflow)

Tags: gridview, viewstate

I have a gridview in a page. fill with a List of Entities. The list is Big. I want to keep it for paging and sorting. but its seems that I got too many data in my viewstate.

Do you have an idea to resolve the overflow still using viewstate.

tank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use viewstate compression see the link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression

Comment: tank you it work perfectly. ( I just had to do a little change. using scriptmanager instead of clientscript, for register the viewstate